# Creating directories with a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, directory

So I would like to create x amount of Directories according to the count of a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
countOfCaptureFiles=$(wc -l < allCaptures.txt)
echo $countOfCaptureFiles

start=1
end=countOfCaptureFiles
for((i=$start;i<=$end;i++))
do
mkdir "SnortAlert${i}"
done
```

In my current testing environment the value of countOfCaptureFiles is 3, so I was hoping to create 3 Directories named SnortAlert1 SnortAlert2 SnortAlert3.

I run the script like so: ./myscript.sh

However when I do this I get errors and no output and I believe it has something to do with assinging end=countOfCaptureFiles but I am not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a `$` in the `end=` assignment.  Make it `end=$countOfCaptureFiles`.

Comment: I have tested your code on my mac. No problems. $ is optional because i<=$end is evaluated i<=countOfCaptureFiles and evaluated again to i<=3. What is the error message? Did you 'chmod +x myscript.sh'?

Comment: You may benefit from a sort standpoint by making all integers you append at the end a fixed width, e.g. `001, 002, 003, ...`. You can use `printf -v name "SnortAlert%03d" "$i"`, then `mkdir "$name"`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is working. But you can minimize using external programs (like wc, cat) like the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while read line;do
    mkdir "SnortAlert${i}"
    let i=i+1
done <allCaptures.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use for in statement to simplify the code like this"

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(cat allCaptures.txt)
for line in $var
do
   mkdir "SnowAlert${line}"
done
```